# tag ec2 instance with stackname

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I want to tag the ec2 instances with key- somekey and otherkey- with the value as stackname. is this going to do the trick with this python code??

```
import os, sys, pprint #standard library imports
import yaml, boto3 #pip library imports
import lib.aws as aws
import config.hooks as hooks


def generate(source_data):
    return yaml.dump(generate_map(source_data), default_flow_style=False)

def generate_resource(ami, source_data):
    resource = {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": ami["ImageId"],
            "InstanceType": ami["InstanceType"],
            "PrivateIpAddress": ami["PrivateIpAddress"],
            "KeyName": ami["KeyName"],
            "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId" },
            "SecurityGroupIds": { "Ref":  "SecurityGroupId" }, 
            "Tags": [
                { "Key": "Name", "Value": ami["Name"] },
                { "Key": "BootUpDependsOn", "Value": ami["BootUpDependsOn"]},
                { "Key": "somekey", "Value": "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}},
                { "Key": "otherkey", "Value": "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}},
                { "Key": "WaitTimeAfterBootUp", "Value": ami["WaitTimeAfterBootUp"]}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting while running this code.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error.  not sure if this is properly formatted.                                                                                 { "Key": "otherkey", "Value": "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}},

Answer (score 1):

CloudFormation [automatically tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html) resources with the following tags:

- aws:cloudformation:logical-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-id
- aws:cloudformation:stack-name

Thus maybe instead of duplicating the tag with `AWS::StackName` you could use those automatically provided.

### Update

There is quotation mark missing in:

```
   { "Key": "otherkey", "Value": "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}},
```

it should be:

```
   { "Key": "otherkey", "Value": "Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}"},
```

it maybe also should be:

```
   { "Key": "otherkey", "Value": {"Fn::Sub": "${AWS::StackName}"}},
```

Comment: I have a lambda function that copies these ec2 tags to the EBS volumes. I had to create them because AWS does not allow you to copy there tags. tags like  aws:cloudformation:stack-name ---can not be copied. i'm having to go the route because tags can not be directly assigned to EBS volumes using CloudFormation.

Comment: @Sniphar I see. Maybe you could also specify tags on stack creation? They propagate to the resources created as well.

Comment: ive tried passing EBS tags in the template but Cloudformation does not support it. There's one other option I've seen out there that user some user data script. this method is a bit difficult because we are creating the CF template from a python code. so for simplicity we just want to pass the tags to the instance the copy it to the EBS with a lambda function. this works well in testing buy i'm trying to deal with the syntax error im getting from the above code.

Comment: @Sniphar Yes, I think that you have no choice then. I updated an answer with possible reason for your error.

Comment: @ Marcin. Thanks for your comment. I finally tested the code.. I went with                                      { "Key": "otherkey", "Value": "Fn::Sub" "${AWS::StackName}"},                                      With no error, here is the result

Comment: - Key: otherkey
   Value: Fn::Sub${AWS::StackName}                                                                                                                                The function did nothing. not sure what went wrong